# Grab all dependencies from apt-get for offline install (Ubuntu 11)

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

How do I use apt-get to install a package on an offline computer? With a separate (connected) computer, I can use `apt-get --download [package]` to pull the package I'm interested in but this fails to grab the dependencies. Can I copy a list of the already installed packages from the offline computer to the online one so the dependencies can be calculated with apt-get?

If I want to install packages and update the computer - is there a better way to do than what's described above?

Comment: Can you not hook it up to the internet to update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tools like [apt-cacher](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-cacher), [apt-mirror](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-mirror) or [apt-offline](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-offline) (which sounds like it fits your requirements best).

apt-offline -

> apt-offline is an Offline APT Package Manager
>
> apt-offline can fully update and upgrade an APT based distribution
>   without connecting to the network, all of it transparent to apt
>
> apt-offline can be used to generate a signature on a machine (with no
>   network). This signature contains all download information required
>   for the apt database system. This signature file can be used on
>   another machine connected to the internet (which need not be a Debian
>   box and can even be running windows) to download the updates. The
>   downloaded data will contain all updates in a format understood by apt
>   and this data can be used by apt-offline to update the non-networked
>   machine.

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks for the heads up on the app and the alternatives!